# como capturo o value deste input quando clico enter no input e sem usar form?

Tags: javascript, html

Como capturo o valor deste *input* quando clico enter no *input* e sem usar form?

Apresento o *input*, abaixo representado:

```
<input id="searchinputid" type="text" class="searchinput"
    name="txtbuscan" placeholder=" Search..." onkeyup="showUser(this.value)"
    autocomplete="off"></input>
```

Comment: Seu HTML é inválido. A tag input não aceita fechamento. Isso pode fazer com que sua página não se comporte corretamente em todos os navegadores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voçe pode usar EventListener para escutar quando uma tecla é pressionada e keyCode para verificar qual é a tecla, e depois XMLHttpRequest para enviar ao php

Como você não disse se usa jquery, segue o exemplo em js puro:

```js
var input_busca = document.querySelector('#searchinputid')//Seleciona a input

input_busca.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
    if (key === 13) { // 13 = verifica se a tecla é o enter, 13 = enter
      alert("Valor local: " + input_busca.value)//Exibe o valor local
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', 'get.php?searchinputid=' + input_busca.value, true);// Informações para enviar ao php
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
      xhr.onload = function () {

          alert("Resposta servidor: " + this.responseText);//Resposta do servidor
      };
      xhr.send();
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="searchinputid" type="text" class="searchinput"
name="txtbuscan" placeholder=" Search..." autocomplete="off">
```

Código de exemplo do get.php

```
<?php

$variavel = $_GET['searchinputid'];

echo $variavel;
```

Answer (score 1):

Utilize o [keyCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_key_keycode.asp) para capturar o enter e recupere o valor do campo chamando a função em algum evento de tecla(keyPress, keyDown ou keyUp).
Ex:

```
function ObterValor(e) {
   if (e.keyCode == 13) {
     return $("#searchinputid").val();
   }
}
```

Comment: e como eu conseguiria guardar esse valor numa variável php?

Comment: Você pode fazer um requisição ajax, por exemplo. (http://www.webmaster.pt/requisicoes-ajax-jquery-2216.html)